# Mysql header files have C++ comments

Tags: mysql, c, header

Using MySQL version 8.0.26 on Red Hat Linux and when I try to compile C programs using MySQL header files, getting errors because they have C++ format comments.
Are there just standard C MySQL header files available?
Thanks..

Comment: C99 standard supports `//` comments. Perhaps your compiler has an option for C99.

Comment: What stone-old compiler do you use?

Comment: if the headers use this maybe they use also something more of C that is more recent then 1990... Use -std=c11 ou C17 ao compilar por exemplo usando gcc